# Can you tell me How Pointers work in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I am new to programming and I am learning C programming language.Is there any video demonstrating the working of a pointer intutively?

Comment: Of course, hundreds of books, tutorials and videos are for free on the internet. Just try to search.

Comment: Time again for Binky: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/104/ http://www.cs.stanford.edu/cslibrary/PointerFunCBig.avi

Answer (score 3):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjo9rfRPQU4

How about this? Pointers are mainly memory addresses to other datatypes

You declare a variable like this:

```
int value;
```

You declare a pointer like this:

```
int* pointer;
```

Because of the pointer being an address, you need to prepend an & (ampersand) infront of the value you'd like to point to, because you're looking for its address. You can assign it like this:

```
pointer = &value;
```